# swi-prolog abs operator not working in clpfd module

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, clpfd

I am doing some toy tests with the CLPFD library in swi-prolog.

Does anybody know why the program below does not work?

```
start(X,Y):- 
   Vars = [X,Y],
   Vars ins 1..3,
   abs(X-Y) #>= 2,
   X #>= Y,
   nl,
   write([X,Y]), nl.
```

The expected answer for start(X,Y) would be X=3 and Y=1. However, swi-prolog indicates me multiple answers. The program works properly if I replace

```
abs(X-Y) #>= 2
```

by

```
X-Y #>= 2
```

My question is whether I am using the abs operator in the right way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, constraints and side-effects do not flock together. Instead, simply stick to the pure part of your program:

```
start(X,Y):- 
   Vars = [X,Y],
   Vars ins 1..3,
   abs(X-Y) #>= 2,
   X #>= Y.
```

And now, query your relation:

```
?- start(X,Y).
   X in 1..3, X#>=Y, abs(X-Y)#>=2, Y in 1..3.
```

The answer is a conditional one:

> Yes, there are solutions for `X` and `Y` provided all these conditions hold.

To get actual values, you have to eliminate all these conditions. You have several options:

In this case, you can use `labeling/2`:

```
?- start(X,Y), labeling([], [X,Y]).
   X = 3, Y = 1.
```

So there is exactly one solution. The `clpfd`-solver alone was not powerful enough to come to this conclusion, it needed some extra help.

Even better would be to use `contracting/1`:

```
?- start(X,Y), clpfd:contracting([X,Y]).
   X = 3, Y = 1.
```

In contrast to labeling, contracting tries to reduce the size of the domain without (visible) search. This makes the solver a bit stronger.

Reasons why the solver is not powerful enough

- in the very general case solving such arithmetic problems is [undecidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems).
- in more specific cases the algorithms would be extremely costly. In fact, there is more than one [diophant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation) in the room.
- even simpler algorithms are very costly in terms of both implementation effort and runtime.
- for many situations, the solver boils down to maintaining consistencies within one constraint<sup>1</sup>. So the only way to "communicate" between different constraints are the domains of variables.

In your case, the abs-constraint admits more solutions!

```
?- [X,Y]ins 1..3, abs(X-Y)#>=2, labeling([],[X,Y]).
   X = 1, Y = 3
;  X = 3, Y = 1.
?- [X,Y]ins 1..3, X-Y#>=2, labeling([],[X,Y]).
   X = 3, Y = 1.
```

What you expect is that the extra constraint `X #>= Y` would help. Alas, the concrete consistency mechanisms are too weak. And not even `X #> Y` helps:

```
?- [X,Y]ins 1..3, abs(X-Y)#>=2, X#>Y.
   X in 2..3, Y#=<X+ -1, abs(X-Y)#>=2, Y in 1..2.
```

However, if you switch from SWI to SICStus, things are a bit different:

```
| ?- assert(clpfd:full_answer).
     
| ?- X in 1..3, Y in 1..3, abs(X-Y)#>=2.
     Y+_A#=X, X in 1..3, Y in 1..3, _A in{-2}\/{2}.
| ?- X in 1..3, Y in 1..3, abs(X-Y)#>=2, X#>Y.
     X = 3, Y = 1.
```

Please note how abs is resolved!

And using SICStus with [`library(clpz)`](https://github.com/triska/clpz) has the same strength:

```
| ?- X in 1..3, Y in 1..3, abs(X-Y)#>=2, X#>Y.
     X = 3, Y = 1.
```

---

<sup>1 Note that I avoid to use the notion of local consistency as opposed to global consistency, since quite often also global consistency only refers to consistency within one "global" constraint.</sup>

Comment: But why the clpfd-solver does provide an instantiation when the abs(X-Y) >= 2 is replaced by X-Y >=2?

The answer shouldn't be the same? Why do we need the labeling for the former but not for the later?

Comment: CLP(FD) in SWI is quite weak. I recommend you use CLP(Z) instead.

Comment: `?(A)` and not `#(A)`?